# Trying to de allocate a vector with a while loop, task manager showing that memory use is increasing

Tags: c++, vector

Okay so I'm trying to learn about vectors, and I made some code to de-allocate the vector:

```
while (!myVector.empty())
{
    myVector.pop_back();
    myVector.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

I expected this to work, but in fact, it increases memory use, and my program is stuck in this loop forever. I have realized that the culprit is the shrink_to_fit function, if I remove it from the loop and only call it once the loop is done, it properly de allocates the memory. But why doesn't it work when I put shrink_to_fit in the loop? I have tried both orientations on the loop including this:

```
while (!myVector.empty())
{
    myVector.shrink_to_fit();
    myVector.pop_back();
}
```

But that doesn't work either. Also, before anyone says so, I am aware that this isn't the most elegant or efficient way to delete vectors.

Edit: As much as I appreciate the answers, I still have absolutely no clue why this isn't just deleting, shrinking, and repeating. I also have no clue why my loop is looping forever, when It should stop once the vector is empty.

Edit: Full source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> myVector;

    cout << "Begin allocation" << endl;
    getchar();

    while (myVector.size() < 1000000)
    {
        myVector.push_back("Nothing Here");
    }

    cout << "Begin de-allocation" << endl;
    getchar();

    while (!myVector.empty())
    {
        myVector.pop_back();
        myVector.shrink_to_fit();
    }

    cout << myVector.size() << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

I should probably state my environment because Neil Kirk has said that this shouldn't cause an infinite loop: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express without any change to the command line, I am running windows 8.1 and I am using Task Manager to monitor the memory usage. Also, the above source is the FULL source, I have not clipped anything off.

Edit: **All right, all right** I've received quite a bit of negative attention for producing the world's most inefficient algorithm :P, but nonetheless, those answers have been helpful. Yes I know it's inefficient, even before posting the source, but first of all It was an experiment, second of all adding a whole lot of elements to the vector was the only way for me to detect the fluctuations in task manager. I have now realized that it wasn't, as I originally thought, an infinite loop. It just takes a while to copy a million or so elements.

Comment: How are you determining that it increases memory use? Any OS-based monitoring tools are unreliable for such checks. The memory is almost certainly released back for use by your program, but typically the C++ library doesn't realease memory back to the OS until program exit.

Comment: I can definitely see changes in task manager whenever allocating/deallocating memory.

Comment: But those changes are less closely related to memory usage of your program than you may think. Try changes of a few 100MB at a time in your program, then it will correlate a bit better.

Comment: @Cakenado Sometimes you can, sometimes you can't. It depends entirely on the implementation. Most implementations allocate larger chunks and divive them into smaller pieces, only (possibly) releasing them back to the OS when they are completely unused. It's possible that your calling `shrink_to_fit` repeatedly is causing fragmentation so none of those chunks ever become unused.

Comment: Shrinking may have to allocate a second array of slightly smaller size, copy the data, and then deallocate the old array. So you will approximately double the amount of memory used by the vector during this process.

Comment: Right, but this doesn't explain why my loop is stuck looping forever. If it does allocate another array and then de-allocate the old one, wouldn't this only be a small spike in memory usage? My memory usage isn't returning to normal.

Comment: I can't see anything that would cause an infinite loop. Other code must be responsible. This could also be responsible for the memory usage.

Comment: Agh. Okay here take a look for yourself, I don't know if it's an infinite loop or if it's just taking forever, I put the full source above.

Comment: Time to use a debugger and find out what happens in the `shrink_to_fit()` calls. I bet it's not looping forever, you've just created the world's most inefficient algorithm

Comment: @Yakk That's all of the code, there is nothing missing.

Comment: @cakenado now it is!  Good, -1 removed.

Comment: Good golly. Does it lock up with only 10 elements, not 1000000??

Comment: I put a million elements in the vector so I could notice the fluctuations in Task Manager.

Comment: Which means the data set is far too large to fit in the CPU cache. It's probably also fragmented the heap and started swapping to disk, making it orders of magnitude slower again. The program basically exercises all the best way to kill performance: poor algorithm, poor data locality, swapping etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `shrink_to_fit` your almost 1000000 element vector is reallocated, then each element is moved to the new version, then the old version is deallocated.

You do this at 1000000 at 999999 at 999998 at 999997 at 999996 at 999995 etc.

This results in 500000500000 `std::string` moves and 1 million allocations during the shrinking portion of your code.

Having requested half-a-trillion operations, it takes a while.

If you don't want the code to do nearly useless things half a trillion times, think about not `shrink_to_fit`ing unless it would matter.  As an example, [only `shrink_to_fit` if `size()` is less than 2/3 `capacity()`](http://ideone.com/LCK89a).

The C++ runtime does not immediately return unused memory to the OS.  When you allocate a million blocks and deallocate them again, you end up with pages of memory owned by the process that are not in use.  Ideally, what would happen is you'd swap between two different huge buffers, with the previously deallocated buffer being used on the next allocation.

Comment: All right, now that makes sense to me. It just takes a while, I assume. I also tested it on my own with 1000 elements instead of a million and the code works fine. Like I've said before, I'm aware of the codes inefficiency, and I will definitely not be using it in any real world application. I was only curious on why it seemed to infinitely loop.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<T>::shrink_to_fit()` will try to reduce the capacity. In the best case you have that `.capacity()` is the same as `.size()` after the call, but that's not ensured. In order to reduce the capacity, `T`s move constructor is going to be used in order to move the old values into a *new* storage. Instead of the usual O(n), you end up with O(n²).

Note that you should need only about twice the original vectors memory. Depending on your operating system and compiler, deallocations might not release memory to the OS directly. On my PC (Win 8.1, MinGW-G++ 4.8.2 from [nuwen](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)), your original vector takes around 55k, and the de-allocation lets the program fluctuate around 59-63k.

There's definitely *some* deallocation, but getting rid of 1,000,000 elements will take a long time, because allocations are slow as hell, and (in worst case) you're allocating in every step of your `while` loop.

Comment: If `.capacity() == .size()` `shrink_to_fit()` will do nothing, especially not move values.

Comment: @nwp: Was talking about the situation _after_ the call, but that wasn't really clear, sorry.

Comment: So how does this increase my memory use? Shouldn't the loop just remove one element and then shrink and then repeat?

Comment: The loop is completely insane, you're probably just going to fragment your heap like that, as well as wasting time copying every element to new storage over and over again. What's wrong with `v.clear(); v.shrink_to_fit();` ?

Comment: Like I said, I know this isn't the best way to go about this problem, I am asking why this is happening.

Comment: It's happening **because** it's the worst possible way to go about the problem. You've made the algorithm exponentially slower. For 1000000 elements you have to create 1000000 vectors, performing 1000001 memory allocations, instead of 2. When people say that choosing the right algorithm is more important than micro-optimisation they mean don't do things like this